# SAML2 for Tomcat8

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, saml, tomcat8, saml-2.0

First, I'm very sorry if this post is too general question. I'm trying to enable SAML2 in my Tomcat8 serverlet. This has been a pain of ass for 2 weeks.

Could anyone who has an experience with this share the documentation or something? I've been searching through Google and trying every option available.

One of the good articles was in this link: 
1- https://medium.com/@chirangaalwis/saml-2-0-based-single-sign-on-and-logout-for-web-applications-deployed-in-apache-tomcat-part-one-6c2dc2df89a3 
-> There is no .jar file in GitHub. /modules/samlsso/target/samlsso-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar
-> I failed to run mvn clean
(So this didn't work)

Any advice will be highly appreciated in advance. Thank you so much.

Comment: You may use https://www.keycloak.org/downloads.html#saml  (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_tomcat_adapter) or if your web-app is Spring based, just use Spring Security SAML extension (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question**:  I'm trying to enable SAML2 in my Tomcat8 serverlet.

There is no .jar file in GitHub. /modules/samlsso/target/samlsso-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar -> I failed to run mvn clean (So this didn't work)

**Answer**:

(1) On Ubuntu 18.04, I run **mvn clean** successfully.

But I failed to **mvn install** due to dependency issue.

(2) On Ubuntu 14.04, I run **mvn clean** successfully.

I also run **mvn install** successfully and modules/samlsso/target/samlsso-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fat.jar was generated.

(3) [Tomcat Extension for SAML SSO](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/tomcat-extension-samlsso) at GitHub repository provides the guidance on how to configure Tomcat8 to enable SAML2, as indicated by Step 3: Add the necessary configurations and libraries.

**Remark**:
The last commit for functionality/feature of [Tomcat Extension for SAML SSO](https://github.com/wso2-extensions/tomcat-extension-samlsso) at GitHub repository was made on Oct 18, 2016 (almost 3 years ago). Therefore, Ubuntu 18.04 was NOT tested at that time.